# Unix server client Connect: Connection refused

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, connect

I am having some problems creating my first server-client application with sockets. I have hardcoded the server's socket address to localhost and the port as 55555. When I try to connect to it from client in a separate terminal typing the command ./player localhost 55555, nothing happens to the server. What I believe should happen is that the server receives data which is "Rock" then prints "Client: ready.\nGo\n    Client: Rock". Instead, the server keeps on waiting with no reaction to player. I suspected that I haven't actually connected to the server so I tried to hardcode the socket address "localhost" into the player connect, as well as the port to 55555 (also hardcoded). I tried running the command ./player and it spews "Connect: Connection Refused". I was wondering how I could fix my hard coded player.c

**referee.c** (this is the server)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    char buf[1024];
    struct sockaddr_in localhost;
    int listenSock, serviceSock, bytesRead;
    size_t len = sizeof(localhost);
    int port = 55555;
    listenSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listenSock<0) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    bzero((char*)&localhost, len);
    localhost.sin_family = AF_INET;
    localhost.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    localhost.sin_port = htons(port);
    bind(listenSock, (struct sockaddr*) &localhost, len);
    printf("Paper, Scissors, Rock game start.\nWaiting for player...\n");
    listen(listenSock, 5);
    do {
        serviceSock = accept(listenSock, 0, 0);
        if(serviceSock == -1){
            perror("Accept");
        }
        else do {
            bzero(buf, sizeof(buf));
            if((bytesRead = read(serviceSock, buf, 1024))<0) {
                perror("Read");
            }
            if(bytesRead > 0){
                printf("Client: ready.\nGo\n    Client: %s\n", buf);
            }
        } while (bytesRead != 0);
        close(serviceSock);
    } while(1);
}
```

**player.c** (client)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char buf[1024], *data = "Rock";
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hp = gethostbyname(argv[1]);
    if (hp == 0) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: unknown host", argv[1] );
        exit(1);
    }
    bcopy( hp->h_addr, &server.sin_addr, hp->h_length );

    server.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(write(sock, data, strlen(data)) < 0) {
        perror("Write");
    }
    close(sock);
}
```

**player.c with hardcoded address/port**

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    struct hostent *hp;
    char buf[1024], *data = "Rock";
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hp = gethostbyname("localhost");
    if (hp == 0) {
        fprintf( stderr, "%s: unknown host", argv[1] );
        exit(1);
    }
    bcopy( hp->h_addr, &server.sin_addr, hp->h_length );

    server.sin_port = 55555;
    if(connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server)) < 0) {
        perror("Connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(write(sock, data, strlen(data)) < 0) {
        perror("Write");
    }
    close(sock);
}
```

Comment: You need to check the result of `bind()` and `listen()` for errors.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
server.sin_port = 55555;
```

It should be:

```
server.sin_port = htons(55555);
```

Comment: Btw if you want an easy way to verify that your server is actually listening on port 55555, you might try doing a "telnet 127.0.0.1 55555" from another shell window while the server is running.  If telnet complains about "connection refused", then your server is not actually listening on that port for whatever reason.

Comment: I got telnet 127.0.0.1 55555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

Comment: I changed my server.sin_port to server.sin_port = htons(55555); also my hp = gethostname("localhost"); I changed to hp = gethostname("127.0.0.1"); it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
 server.sin_port = 55555;
```

to :

```
server.sin_port = htons(55555);
```

Is working.

Comment: I have tried this, but the same thing happened. Do you get the server to print the line "Client: ready. \nGo\n    Client: Rock". Also I have run a test on my bind() in referee.c and it seems to return -1. So I am figuring the error is in bind now

Comment: yes.bind() is working fine for me. do ps -e to see if same process is running before.

Comment: my output is like:
bind : Success
Paper, Scissors, Rock game start.
Waiting for player...
listen :: Success
Client: ready.
Go
    Client: Rock